# Capture the outcome of an assert statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

I am writing a test helper and it has this method:

```
def todo msg = ''
  assert false, '@TODO: ' + msg
end
```

Basically I want a quick method to fail a test. Next, I would like to test this method (because it will be encapsulated in a shippable helper). So I would like to write something like this:

```
test 'todo' do
  result = todo
  expected = '@TODO: '
  assert_equal expected, result
end
```

but it just fails when `assert false` gets called. So, how would I test this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This helper is supposed to work with `Test::Unit`, is that right? I believe that `assert false` throws an exception which is caught by `Test::Unit`. You could just wrap the call to `todo` in a `begin...rescue` block and catch that exception.

The `test/unit` which comes in the Ruby standard libraries is actually `Minitest::Unit` -- when an assertion fails, it raises a `Minitest::Assertion` exception. You could `rescue` that.

For the "real" `Test::Unit`, it raises a `Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError` when an assertion fails.

Comment: Please note that if you want to catch *any* exception, you need to use `rescue Exception`, *not* just `rescue`. There are some exceptions which will not be caught by a bare `rescue`.

Comment: If this helps you, a +1 would be appreciated.